# How does Mathematica determine the number of points to plot implicitly?

Tags: plotting

What is the logic that Mathematica (or other software, if this information is not public) uses to determine how many points are needed to plot implicit equations?

[This discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69421/plot-of-implicit-equations) seems to suggest that Mathematica essentially goes through all pixels in the plotting region and decides 1 by 1, whether to colour it. However, when I try the following 2 plots which visually have about the same surface area, I get that Mathematica uses ~3000 points to plot the first one and ~11000 points to plot the second one. Why is there such a discrepancy? Also, what happens after picking the points? Does the software just connect them piecewise linearly?

```
P1 = ContourPlot3D[x[1]^4 + x [1] x[2]^3 + x[2] - x[3]^2 == 0, {x[1], -100, 100}, {x[2], -100, 100}, {x[3], -100, 100}]
Dimensions[P1[[1, 1, 1]]][[1]]
```

and I get 3405 points

versus

```
P2 = ContourPlot3D[x[1]^4 x[2]^3 - 45 x[2] x[3]^2 == 0, {x[1], -100, 100}, {x[2], -100,100}, {x[3], -100, 100}]
Dimensions[P2[[1, 1, 1]]][[1]]
```

and I get 10950 points.